# Align Contents of a String C#

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm using the `iTextSharp` extension to output data to a PDF file. I am using a `For loop` to dynamically output the data, which is on an XML form. The problem I'm having is aligning the contents of a row or in this case 'paragraph' that is being written to the pdf page.  The current output is this:

```
__ 0002 dog name              breed              John Doe
__ 0004 Kona                 Doberman             Jesus Montero
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
__ 0002 dog name             breed                John Doe
__ 0004 Kona                 Doberman             Jesus Montero
```

Keep in mind that these are simply two strings being written to the pdf file on two separate loops in the `For loop`. The code that adds the strings is:

```
iText.Paragraph dogEntryParagraph = new iText.Paragraph(
  (   "__   "
    + String.Format( "{0,-40}{1,-40}{2,-40}{3,-40}" ,
        armBandString ,
        dogNameString ,
        breedString   ,
        ownerNameString
        )
  ) ,
  _smallFont
  ) ;
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong trying to align the breed and owner name within the strings? I have spent a lot of time and can get it close, but not exactly what I need.

Comment: Please note that it messed up the formatting.  Basically what you need to know is that I have a single string which is a row of data with four values that need to be left aligned as if they were in four columns.  And NO using a table is not an effective option in this instance.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, your only other option is to put the text at specific coordinate. In other words - implement the Table functionality yourself. I don't see any reason to do that when you've been provided with that code already. Trust me, I've been down this road already. Learn from my mistakes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a table. I had this problem myself with iTextSharp - even if you use a monospaced font, what you are trying to do won't work unless you draw the text at specific coordinates and then you blow up the flow layout. So, the best way to do tabular data in iTextSharp is with a table...

Create the table first as an object, then add it to your flow...

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

table.addCell("Dog Name");
table.addCell("Breed");

table.addCell("Akira");
table.addCell("Chinese Crested");

table.addCell("Kaika");
table.addCell("Greyhound");

document.add(table);
```

This really works nicely, and you can add formatted objects to the cells if you want, or images or whatever. You can also add borders and other things...

http://www.geek-tutorials.com/java/itext/itext_table.php

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me so much headache and frustration. I had no idea it was an iTextSharp issue.

Comment: It's actually PDF issue - iTextSharp is bound by the PDF standard, so they have to implement it this way. Makes it hard on us sometimes but it's important to have a standard and follow it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using a monospace font in this case. That would ensure that each space and character is a fixed length.